# Calculating permutations in python?

Tags: python

I have an array like so:

`l = [1, 4, 6, 3, 2]`

For each element in this array I can either 'take it' or not. I want to be able to calculate every combination of elements that I can take where there are 2^n combinations. For this example, there would be 32 possible arrangements.

For example, I can take:
`[1,4,6]` or `[3,2]` or `[1,5]` or `[1,4,6,3,2]`, etc.

What is the best way to do this in Python? Is this a problem where I can make use of the itertools library?

Comment: Hi, ask Google first! https://docs.python.org/3.5/library/itertools.html

Comment: combination or permutation - in a permutation [1,2] is different to [2,1] in a combination they are equivalent

Answer (score 3):

- `itertools.permutations` will return all permutations of a given length.
- `itertools.combinations` will return all combinations of a given length.

Which one you want depends on whether you care about ordering or not - `(1, 2)` and `(2, 1)` are different permutations but the same combination.

You can pair that with `itertools.chain` to create an iterable of all permutations/combinations of all lengths.

```
from itertools import chain, permutations, combinations

# Note: if you want to include the empty combo/permutation, change the first
#       argument of the range() calls to 0.
all_length_perms = chain(permutations(l, n) for n in range(1, len(l)+1))
all_length_combos = chain(combinations(l, n) for n in range(1, len(l)+1))

# Example usage once you have the iterable...
for perm in all_length_perms:
    print(perm)
```

Answer (score 1):

Definitely use itertools:

```
 l = [1, 4, 6, 3, 2]
 for length in range(2, len(l)+1):
     for p in itertools.permutations(l, length)
         print p
```

There are lots of them

Answer (score 0):

Use `itertools` module

short unintelligible answer:

```
from itertools import chain, combinations
l = [1, 4, 6, 3, 2]
all_combinations = [i for i in chain(*(combinations(l, j) for j in range(len(l)+1)))]
```

explanation:

```
combinations(iterable, r) --> combinations object

Return successive r-length combinations of elements in the iterable.
```

we need to get the combination for r = 0 to len(l) + 1
we use chain to combine each of the combinations